# Unmask pipewire service?

Tags: pipewire

currently have no audio out. When I try to restart pipewire, I get the following

```
systemctl --user restart pipewire{,-pulse}.{socket,service} pipewire-media-session.service
Failed to restart pipewire-media-session.service: Unit pipewire-media-session.service is masked.
```

not sure how to unmask this service

Comment: You unmask it with `systemctl --user unmask pipewire-media-session.service`